# How to estimate expected total variation distance between conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space and let $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ be a filtration on this space.

Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and suppose that for all $n$, the conditional probabilities of $P$ and $Q$ given $\mathcal{F}_n$ are regular, i.e. $P(\cdot \mid \mathcal{F}_n)(\omega)$ and $Q(\cdot \mid \mathcal{F}_n)(\omega)$ are probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

For convenience, write $P^n = P(\cdot \mid \mathcal{F}_n)$ and similarly for $Q^n$.

Let $d$ be the total variation distance, i.e. $d(P,Q) = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{F}}|P(A) - Q(A)|$. I need some help proving the following.

**Claim.** If $d(P,Q) < \alpha \beta$, then $P(\{\omega: d(P^n(\omega), Q^n(\omega)) > \alpha\}) < \beta$. (The Lemma on p.405 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Teddy_Seidenfeld/publication/223097171_An_approach_to_consensus_and_certainty_with_increasing_evidence/links/0c960529c9d31ab5ab000000.pdf).)

My first thought was to use Markov's inequality to get
$$P(d(P^n, Q^n) > \alpha) \leq \alpha^{-1}E_P(d(P^n, Q^n)).$$

Now, the claim would follow if I could show that $d(P^n, Q^n)< \alpha \beta$ a.s. ($P$), but the best I can do is use the triangle inequality to get

$$d(P^n, Q^n) \leq d(P^n,P) + d(Q^n, Q) + d(P,Q) < 2 + \alpha \beta.$$

Then $P(d(P^n, Q^n) > \alpha) < 2/\alpha + \beta$. I'm stuck trying to improve this.

*Addendum.* On second thought, the above estimate doesn't improve the trivial estimate $P(d(P^n, Q^n) > \alpha) \leq 1$ for small $\alpha$, so probably a different approach is needed. Perhaps we can show that $d(P^n, Q^n) < d(P,Q)$ a.s. (P), but I don't see how to do it yet. Hints are appreciated.

Comment: First of all, it is not even clear to me why the function $\omega \mapsto d(P^n(\omega), Q^n(\omega))$ is measurable with respect to $\cal F$. If the space $\Omega$ is polish or something, then we could perhaps replace that (generally) uncountable supremum with a countable one. But in general I don't see any reason for that probability to be defined.

Comment: @Shalop Thanks, yes, I was worried about that too. Perhaps I'll need to include more details about the set up from the paper I'm reading, which can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Teddy_Seidenfeld/publication/223097171_An_approach_to_consensus_and_certainty_with_increasing_evidence/links/0c960529c9d31ab5ab000000.pdf). The question is about the Lemma on p. 405, if you're interested.

Comment: @Shalop Perhaps the measurability follows by noting that $d$ can be represented as the difference between the two probabilities of the set where one has a larger Radon-Nikodym derivative than the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by showing $E_P[d(P^n,Q^n)] < \alpha \beta$ rather than $d(P^n,Q^n) < \alpha \beta \  a.s.$  We need to show $E_P[d(P^n,P)] = 0$
 and $E_P[d(Q^n,Q)] = 0$ for a sharper bound.

For the former statement, let $\mu$ denote a mutually dominating measure (for instance $P+P^n$). Let $f_P$ and $f_{P^n}$ denote corresponding densities.  Now, using the fact that the supremum is attained by $A = \{f_{P_n} \geq f_P\}$, we have that
$E_P[d(P^n,P)] = E_P[ P(A|h_t) - P(A) ]$.  Taking iterated expectations, it follows that $E_Pd(P^n,P) = 0$.

The proof of the latter statement is identical, since we can choose the random variable we condition on with iterated expectation.

Comment: I'm no longer convinced by your argument. Since $P_n$ is a probability-measure-valued random variable, the set $A$ in your argument depends on $\omega$. So we are really computing $$E_P[d(P^n,P)] = \int [P_n(A(\omega))(\omega) - P(A(\omega))]P(d\omega),$$ right? And it's not clear to me that this integral equals $0$.

Comment: The total variation distance is non-negative, so $E[d(P^n,P)]=0$ implies that $P^n=P$ a.s. which is clearly not necessarily true.